# Оптимизировать запрос

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, 
Есть запрос

```
  SELECT * FROM sh_catalog AS catalog WHERE catalog.id_cat=47 AND catalog.id in (SELECT good_id FROM sh_cat_options_values WHERE option_id=265 AND value='морозильная камера' )
```

Идет выборка товара, один из параметров которого иммет значение "морозильная камера".
Запрос выполняется 2.5 секунды. Можно его как то оптимизировать?
При EXPLAIN выдает следующее: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постройте отсутствующие индексы по тем столбцам, по которым задаются критерии отбора.

Comment: а не подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: Смотрите команду CREATE INDEX или в GUI мышкой.